# Cauchy Sequences Lemma in Vector Space E

Tags: sequences-and-series, vector-spaces, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, cauchy-sequences

I ran into a Lemma.

Suppose $||.||_1$ and  $||.||_2$ are two norms in vector spapce E, such that $||.||_1$ and  $||.||_2$ are equivalent norms and {$x_n$} is an equivalent in E, then {$x_n$} is cauchy sequence in (E, $||.||_1$) if and only if {$x_n$} is cauchy sequence in (E, $||.||_2$).

my friends would help me, how prove this lemma? i try to familiar with cuachy sequences recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $||.||_1 \sim ||.||_2$ (are equivalent) then there exists two constants $c, C > 0$ such that for all $ x \in E$ we have:

$$c||x||_1 \leq ||x||_2  \leq C||x||_1$$

Now if $(x_n)$ is cauchy with respect to $||.||_1$, it means that given $\varepsilon > 0$, we have $$||x_n  - x_m||_1 < \dfrac{\varepsilon}{C}$$ if $n,m$ are bigh enough. But this means that

$$||x_n - x_m||_2  \leq C||x_n - x_m||_1 < \varepsilon$$

Comment: Dear @Aram, i accept it, but would you please add a bit more detail?

Comment: i means we have a bi directional if.  how with this each of side be prooved?

Comment: @Okh.Pij You just use the other inequality: $c||x||_1 \leq ||x||_2$, the same proof applies.